# Discord.js Applying System?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am currently writing an application system in my Discord bot.

The system looks like this:

You react to a message and get a message via DM then he asks about 5 questions (1 question, the user writes the answer, then the next one follows etc.) At the end there should be a message "Thank you for your application". Then the bot should send the answers in a channel on my Discord but sorted according to the questions.

```
What is your name (question 1):

I'm blah blah blah

How old are you (question 2):

Second Answer

...
```

after that there should be a react system, that is, you press a reaction, the bot gives the applicant the role and delete the message, but that comes afterwards.

Now to the problemL I manage to react to the message, and the person gets the DM, but how do you write the questions in an embed message and then send them in a channel as described above?

This is the current code:

```
bot.on("messageReactionAdd", async (reaction, user) => {
    let message = reaction.message,
        emoji = reaction.emoji;
    if (emoji.name == "") {
        if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
        if (user === bot.user) return;
        reaction.users.remove(user);


user.send("Welcome to your Application")

const questions = [                    
    "What is your name?",                  
    "How old are you?",                  
    "Question 3?",  
    "Question 4?"            
  ];                                     
  
  const applying = [];

  bot.on("message", async message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
  
      if (applying.includes(message.author.id)) return;
  
      try {
        console.log(`${message.author.tag} began applying.`);
  
        applying.push(message.author.id);
        await message.channel.send(":pencil: **Application started!** Type `#cancel` to exit.");
  
        for (let i = 0, cancel = false; i < questions.length && cancel === false; i++) {
          await message.channel.send(questions[i]);
          await message.channel.awaitMessages(m => m.author.id === message.author.id, { max: 1, time: 300000, errors: ["time"] })
            .then(async collected => {

                application[questions[i]] = collected.first().content

              if (collected.first().content.toLowerCase() === "#cancel") {
                await message.channel.send(":x: **Application cancelled.**");
                applying.splice(applying.indexOf(message.author.id), 1);
                cancel = true;

                console.log(`${message.author.tag} cancelled their application.`);
              }
            }).catch(async() => {
              await message.channel.send(":hourglass: **Application timed out.**");
              applying.splice(applying.indexOf(message.author.id), 1);
              cancel = true;
  
              console.log(`${message.author.tag} let their application time out.`);
            });
        }
  
        await message.channel.send(":thumbsup: **You're all done!**")
        

        await console.log(`${message.author.tag} finished applying.`);
      } catch(err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
      


      let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()    
    .setColor('#1D1D1D') 
    .setAuthor('New Application',)
    .addField("What is your name?", `${}`)
    .addField("How old are you?", `${}`)
    .addField("Question 3", `${}`)
    .addField("Question 4", `${}`)
    .addField("Datum:", message.createdAt.toLocaleString())
    
      let sChannel1 = message.guild.channels.cache.get("721515009871577089")
      sChannel1.send(embed)
 
     

  });








        }     
    }
);
```

Comment: Please show the code you currently have.

Comment: I add the current Code ;D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at `MessageCollector` event in Discord.js. [This article](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html) might be helpful for you.

> *Don't be confused with `ReactionCollector` and emojis reaction it's very different things*

After that you should store user's data (answers) somehow, *in your DB for example*.

Also, to send a embedded message with answers you should know the exact ID of your channel, or request it from Discord server/guild by [`systemChannelID`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=systemChannelID).

> *Also, your bot should been able (have a permission) to send messages in this channel.*

The example of sending a message for Discord ~v11:

```
//inside async/await function
    let embed = new MessageEmbed();
    embed.setTitle("Test")
    await message.channel.send(embed );
```

Usefull embeded generators can be found [here](https://leovoel.github.io/embed-visualizer/) or [here](https://cog-creators.github.io/discord-embed-sandbox/)

Comment: Thank You, I will try it later!